# if else not providing desired output

Tags: python

My conditional function is not working. Where is the issue?

From  the below text, if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" available, then it will print the name.

```
DFF  DFF  Manufacturing  Company  QWE  LIMITED 
DFF  Strasse  16  O  Strasse  103 
96032,  Germany  23467,  Germany
```

Python code:

```
if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" in text.split('\n'):
    print("DFF Manufacturing Company")
```

Output:
No result is showing

Comment: When you do the `text.split()`, you're doing an exact match against the list generated by splitting, instead of a substring match.

Comment: So. err, _why_ do the `split()` at all? Just take out the function call and the code will do what you're asking for.

Comment: That is to say, `if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" in text:`, and there you are.

Comment: ...to make it be true _with the `split()`_, you would need something more like `if "DFF  DFF  Manufacturing  Company  QWE  LIMITED" in text.split()`

Comment: ...or if you want to compare against only the first line, then maybe `if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" in text.split()[0]:`

Comment: I understood now. If I use text in stead of text.split(), it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to split lines and need to check every line, you have to check by loop.

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
   if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" in line:
      print("DFF Manufacturing Company")
      #break #if you want to check once
```

if you want to check in full paragraph , use below code

```
if "DFF  Manufacturing  Company" in text:
    print("DFF Manufacturing Company")
```